# shipping price not updated in first time?

Tags: cart, shipping, magento1.9.2.4

I am using magento 1.9.2.4.
I was added a product to cart. Select country and click on get quite button. 
it's provide me table rate shipping charges according to my zone. I clicked on update total button. but shipping price not added in cart value.And when I refresh the page, it's added in cart.
Here is my [product link](http://eifel-hunger.de/butterscotch-pmt-f1-og.html) 
 Please guide me. I am in magento.

Comment: please help me gyz

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue my self. The issue was conflict by an extension. So I deactivated the extension and now it's working fine